# Using Grails g.link to generate RESTful URIs

Tags: rest, grails

I'm trying to generate a RESTful URI (i.e. `$controller/$id`) with Grails 3.1 but I'm getting the standard Grails (i.e. `$controller/$action/$id`).

Here's the code from my .gson file

```
href: "${g.link(controller: "credentialProvider", action: "show", id: instanceSnapshot.instance.credentialProvider.id)}"
```

and it's generating

```
"href": "/credential-provider/show/1"
```

but I want it to generate

```
"href": "/credential-providers/1"
```

Is it possible to generate RESTful URIs with g.link?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You best bet could be `UrlMappings`.

Comment: Did you try `g.link()` with *uri*, *url* or *mapping*? https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html